# Nonlinear differential equation type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which method should I use for solving equation
$\sqrt{1-x^2}dy + \sqrt{1-y^2}dx = 0$ ?

Comment: separable equations...

Comment: [integrals of irrational functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_irrational_functions)

Comment: @pedja: I don't think he is asking that. I think he is interested in knowing if $\sin^{-1}(x) = \cos^{-1}(y)$, then how does one solve for $y$.

Comment: Ah never mind, for some reason I had $dy$ and $dx$ switched. Yes, just use separation of variables.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar,question is about method for solving DE. Which method you suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the perfect hints by pedja and  user7530. So dividing both sides by $\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}$ you will be left with something like $$d(\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y)=0.$$ You may also wish to write the general solution as $$x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}=c$$ or $$x=c\sqrt{1-y^2}-y\sqrt{1-c^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, after dividing with $\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}$ problem looks much simpler.